# window.open does not reuse existing named window?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tomcat7

We have an application running in Tomcat 7

We are trying to open a window from our application using javascript, each time an event is called using `window.open('url', 'name', '');`

But what happens is that each time an event is called a new window is opened and the information is loaded, but it should open one window initially for the first event and for the following events it should reload the information in the same window.

We were able to avoid that situation, what we did was

We used to call our application which is deployed in a different server with the url as follows (`http://servername.domain.com:8080/applicaationname`), where the above issue happens

But when we call it as `http://servername:8080/applicaationname`, it works fine as expected

what is causing this behavior?

Many Thanks,
cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In the Internet Zone (which is where your code runs when you use a fully-qualified-domain-name like servername.domain.com) your code has restricted permissions. In the Intranet Zone (which is where your code runs when you use a dotless hostname like servername) there are fewer restrictions on permissions.

The problem you're encountering is that in the Internet Zone, a named window launched from site "A" may not be navigated by JavaScript from site "B"-- instead a new window is created. We introduced this change in IE8 for security reasons, and it matches other browsers and what HTML5 demands.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565638(v=vs.85).aspx for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer it was very helpful in understanding this behaviour. But we have another situation, we have the same application deployed in another server of different domain. In that, when the url is accessed(in different environment) with the domain it is working fine as expected but it is accessed without domain it is opening a new window each time. as you say if this is due to internet and intranet behaviour, is there any way we can configure such that it behaves the same across different domains?